# Error trying to connect to VPN after being disconnected

Tags: windows, windows-10, vpn

I have a PPTP VPN connection on Windows 10. I can connect to it fine at first, but if I suspend my VM (I'm running Win 10 on VMWare Fusion) and later resume and try to connect to the VPN it usually gives me the following error (I say usually because it works on a rare occasion):

"A connection to the remote computer could not be established. You might need to change the network settings for this connection."

I've found nothing to get it working, my only solution is signing out of Windows and back in, then it will always work. But that's a pretty annoying solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I’d suggest you re-install the TCP/IP Protocol first and disable Ipv6 from using (only Ipv4 enable) on client side.

If this issue still persists, refer to following link for more reference, lots of suggestions and practice have been mentioned.

PPTP VPN on Windows 7 - error 720

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/eb37b71e-a021-47ee-896e-186cef55bf11/pptp-vpn-on-windows-7-error-720?forum=w7itpronetworking

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why but an easier workaround you can try is go to Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings and uncheck *Use a proxy server for your LAN* if it is checked. Then try to reconnect again.

This worked for me on Forticlient VPN client though but it may also work for your VPN client